# Making a RelativeLayout scrollable

Tags: android, xml

I want my RelativeLayout to be scrollable in Landscape.
I tried doing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".RelativeActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/headline_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/relative_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/layout_uebersicht" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative_textview"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/relativebutton_linearlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onButtonLinearLayoutClick"
                android:text="@string/linear_layout" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/relativebutton_tablelayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onButtonTableLayoutClick"
                android:text="@string/table_layout" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/relativebutton_framelayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onButtonFrameLayoutClick"
                android:text="@string/frame_layout" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/relativebutton_gridlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onButtonGridLayoutClick"
                android:text="@string/grid_layout" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[But it messes everything up like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRq26.png)

I have also tried putting a simple LinearLayout between the ScrollView and the RelativeLayout and switching all the layout_height and width values around. None of this will work.

The `android:fillViewport="true"` does not work either.

[My code looks like this without the ScrollView:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RUOm.png)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context=".RelativeActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/headline_icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/relative_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/layout_uebersicht" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relative_textview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/relativebutton_linearlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onButtonLinearLayoutClick"
            android:text="@string/linear_layout" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/relativebutton_tablelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onButtonTableLayoutClick"
            android:text="@string/table_layout" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/relativebutton_framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onButtonFrameLayoutClick"
            android:text="@string/frame_layout" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/relativebutton_gridlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onButtonGridLayoutClick"
            android:text="@string/grid_layout" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/baseline_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to wrap the relative layout inside horisontal oriented LinearLayout. By the way, since Relative layout will be  deprecated, consider using constraint layout. It will definitely work with scrollview. Just set height and width to match_parent for constraint layout

Comment: Yea, I know. I just have to use the RelativeLayout since it's asked in my exercise. I will try the LinearLayout when I'm home. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately your solution does not work for me :/

Answer (score 0):

Create a `HorizontalScrollView` and inside it , design your `RelativeLayout`  like this :

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/headline_icon" />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/relative_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="@string/layout_uebersicht" />

            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/relative_textview"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/relativebutton_linearlayout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:onClick="onButtonLinearLayoutClick"
                            android:text="@string/linear_layout" />

                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/relativebutton_tablelayout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:onClick="onButtonTableLayoutClick"
                            android:text="@string/table_layout" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/relativebutton_framelayout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:onClick="onButtonFrameLayoutClick"
                            android:text="@string/frame_layout" />

                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/relativebutton_gridlayout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:onClick="onButtonGridLayoutClick"
                            android:text="@string/grid_layout" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/baseline_icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Consider that your `RelativeLayout` width should be `wrap_content`

Comment: Does not work for me. Now it looks like this https://imgur.com/a/tNz3SRI

Comment: @RenéSpies do you want to scroll all image or button or button and image together? i want to edit code

Comment: The exercise says that all views should be showed. So its possible to either scroll both or just the buttons in the linearlayout.